# Set the value of one column to the other

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table, I want to set a value of one column to in another column.
Here is a table.

```
 id         name          format
 1          azeem          <h1>value of name column</h1>
 2          arfan          <b>value of name column</b>
```

I want to set the value of `name` column in a `format` column.
The value of `name` table is update after some time. I want that whenever I select the `format` column it automatically set the value of `name` table in the `format` table.
In this case like that.

```
 format
  <h1>azeem</h1>
  <b>arfan</b>
```

Comment: I would question why you have the `format` column at all. Just handle the output formatting in your PHP code.

Comment: You might instead have a column which contains values like `h1` and `b` to indicate what type of HTML tag should be wrapped around the value on output, but don't store the HTML in the database.

Comment: how can I fix this in `php` if I have 100 rows instead of 2 ?

Answer (score 0):

```
 update `mytable` set 
          `mytable`.`format`= CONCAT('<b>', `mytable`.`name`, '</b>');
```

... but as the comments mention: free of purpose ...

Comment: This is only update only single row. If I have 100 rows than ?

Comment: As there's no where-clause, it will surely screw through the entire table!

Comment: @Axel this is just a single format every row has a unique format.